# My query does not output the column I want even when selected

Tags: php, sql, select

Not sure how I am getting the undefined index error when  my SELECT already gets the column that I want.

I have three tables:

**clinics_branch.add.php**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once('clinics_branch_list.vc.php');
?>

<?php echo $lstBranch['usrmerchant']; ?>
```

the undefined index is in the echo usrmerchant

**clinics_branch_list.vc.php**

```
require_once($routePath . "_mc/Merchant.mc.php");
  $mcMerchant = new Merchant_MC();

$lstBranch = $mcMerchant->SelectMainBranch_ByMerchantBranch($db, $merchantid);
```

**Merchant.mc.php**

```
Class Merchant_MC {

  public function SelectMainBranch_ByMerchantBranch($db, $merchantid) {
  $stmt = $db->prepare(
    " SELECT  mb.merchantid, m.usrmerchant
      FROM `merchant_branch` mb
      LEFT JOIN `merchant` m ON mb.merchantid = m.merchantid
      WHERE mb.merchantid = $merchantid "
  );

  $stmt->bindValue(':merchantid', $merchantid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
  $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  return $row;
  }
}
```

here's the output of my select, as you can see there is content so the SQL is working

[image: 1]

any help is appreciated, the full error is:

```
Notice: Undefined index: usrmerchant in clinics_branch_add.php
```

**UPDATE:**

changing my SQL line to `WHERE mb.merchantid = :merchantid` still shows the same error.

**UPDATE:**

switching to innjer join does not work either

SELECT mb.merchantid, m.usrmerchant 
   FROM merchant_branch mb 
INNER JOIN merchant m 
   ON mb.merchantid = m.merchantid 
WHERE mb.merchantid = :merchantid

Comment: Your prepared statement isn't quite correct, you should have `WHERE mb.merchantid = :merchantid` so that `merchantid` is the bind parameter in your `bindValue()` call.

Comment: did that change, the same error stays

Comment: Have you tried using something like `print_r($row);` to see what you have in your data (may be something to do with having `mb.merchantid` as the column in your SQL ).

Comment: how do you use $lstBranch?

Comment: i did the print_r($lst_branch) and im getting the number and usrmerchant i want in the array.

Comment: See Nick's answer below.

Comment: i use $lstBranch byt trying to output the content in the page like echo $lstBranch['usrmerchant']; or echo $lstBranch['merchantid'];

Comment: $lstBranch will have first index of table, next index is column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a [`fetchAll`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), so `$lstBranch` will actually be an array of rows looking something like this:

```
array(0 => array('merchantid' => 30, 'usrmerchant' => 'dermadent'))
```

and you will need to access the `usrmerchant` value as

```
$lstBranch[0]['usrmerchant'];
```

Comment: i see, i was missing out on the array, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
SELECT  mb.merchantid, m.usrmerchant
      FROM `merchant_branch` mb
      LEFT JOIN `merchant` m ON mb.merchantid = m.merchantid
      WHERE mb.merchantid = $merchantid "
```

To

```
SELECT mb.merchantid, m.usrmerchant 
   FROM merchant_branch mb 
INNER JOIN marchant m 
   ON mb.merchantid = m.merchantid 
WHERE mb.merchantid = :merchantid
```

Comment: i still get undefined index, i dont think the select sql is the problem since i already have the output wanted working.